# Where are these nullptr located?

Tags: c++, nullptr

```
int* x = nullptr;
class_example* obj = nullptr;
```

I understand what nullprt is, but where are these variables x and obj located?

Heap? or Stack?

Comment: Impossible to tell from the given code sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointers are just ordinary variables, that happen to have *values* that are addresses of other objects (and those addresses could be on the heap).

So in this snippet:

```
int main() 
{
  int* x = nullptr;
  class_example* obj = nullptr;
}
```

just like regular local variables, these pointers will be located on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int* x = nullptr;
> class_example* obj = nullptr;
> ```
>
> where are these variables x and obj located?

These variables have static storage duration, because they are declared in the namespace scope without thread_local keyword. The language standard does not specify where the objects will be located. It is up to the language implementation to decide.

> Heap? or Stack?

Typically, neither.

For example, in the ELF executable format, zero initialised static variables would be located in memory segment named BSS.